# Do I need the Perl bin directory in the PATH to run perl programs (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl, path-variables

Traditionally, I would just have `C:\perl\bin` in my PATH variable, but due to version conflicts I would like to keep different perl versions at locations `C:\Perl-versionXY\bin` and just execute my Perl scripts via directly invoking `C:\Perl-...\bin\perl.exe theScript.pl`.

This is actually to be run under an automated system, where we *already directly invoke* `C:\perl\bin\perl.exe` for all perl scripts. (But `C:\perl\bin` is *also* in the PATH.)

To facilitate different Perl versions side-by-side, I'd like to *remove C-perl-bin from the PATH* to make sure we don't ever see side effects from any Perl related PATH settings.

Is this supposed to work? What about modules that require additional DLL files (like LibXML, that requires the LibXML.dll in the bin directory of perl)??

I'll be using Strawberry Perl portable for the side by side versions. (Who's readme file mentions some PATH settings, but doesn't mention which is used for what.)

Comment: did you mean `C:\bin\perl`, because that would make a lot more sense

Comment: @johncorbett: why would that make more sense? Windows isn't unix, so it has no c:\bin. C:\perl\bin makes perfectly sense, IMHO

Comment: Haha, I guess unix is just so drilled into my head, even on windows I use cygwin

Comment: c\perl\bin is perfectly correct (and the default location for ActiveState's perl which is what we used up to now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that all the DLLs are in the same directory as the executable, it should work normally.  If there is only one entry for Perl in the path, then the DLLs must be in the same directory as the executable (or are being found using some explicit logic) so you should be OK.  When an executable loads a DLL, the first place searched is the directory containing the executable.

If you do run into trouble, one option would be to create a command file for each version.  You could give these different names, like perl58.cmd, perl514.cmd, etc., put them all in a single directory, and put that directory on the path.  In each command file, add the corresponding Perl directory to the path and then launch Perl with the command-line arguments:

```
setlocal
PATH=c:\perl58\bin;%PATH%
perl %*
```

Note use of the `setlocal` command so that the change to the path is not exported back to the command line window you're running the command file from.

Answer (score 0):

I would caution that if you do not have the Perl bin directory on the PATH, and anything that you executes attempts to invoke program that lives in the bin dir without providing an explicit path (bad practice, but that doesn't stop it from happening) then you get failure, and depending on how that failure is handled, could manifest in problems that are subtle and hard to debug.

So I say, unless you have a very compelling reason not to add it (e.g. IT policy that makes it  prohibitively hard and annoying to add to PATH), then add it.

Comment: Well, if I have two perl versiin, one say 5.8 and one 5.14, I can only meaningfully add one of these to the (global) path. It would be the wrong path for the other version. So it just doesn't seem to make any sense to add it to th (global) path at all and it would be lts easier to not have it in the path than to be required to set it context dependent.

Comment: It is a common practice on Unix systems to wrap executables with shell scripts which configure the environment in which the executable will run.  Is there a reason you can't wrap the invocations of your perl programs in batch or powerShell scripts?